# unable to build opencv for android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to build opencv pulled from github for android

I am running following command

```
cd ~/extProjects/opencv && cd build_android && cmake -DANDROID_SDK_TOOLS=~/Android/Sdk/tools -DANDROID_NDK=~/Android/Sdk/ndk/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/extProjects/opencv/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-32 -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./install ~/extProjects/opencv && make
```

NDK path is correct and here is the version  ~/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393
But I am getting following error

```
CMake Error at platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake:628 (message):
  Could not find any working toolchain in the NDK.  Probably your Android NDK
  is broken.
```

Any suggestions where to look for and fix this ?

Comment: Perhaps change this `-DANDROID_NDK=~/Android/Sdk/ndk/` to be `-DANDROID_NDK=~/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/`  As now Android support side-by-side installations of the NDK they have moved to versioned subdirectories.

Comment: i tried. still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after having to do additional defines

```
cd ~/extProjects/opencv && cd build_android && cmake -DANDROID_SDK_TOOLS=/your/home/path/Android/Sdk/build-tools -DANDROID_SDK_TOOLS_VERSION=33.0.1 -DANDROID_SDK=/your/home/path/Android/Sdk -DANDROID_NDK=~/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-30 -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./install ~/extProjects/opencv && make
```

Also note for the android SDK path, giving "~" for home directory does not work

Compilation has started.. have to now see if I can get it work :|

Comment: I have tried a lot of options to build OpenCV for Android. No one works properly. In my opinion the easiest solution is recent guide released by OpenCV team: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Custom-OpenCV-Android-SDK-and-AAR-package-build

The only thing needed is adjust versions for existing environment to compose config.py like this: cmake_vars=dict(ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION='4.1.2', GRADLE_VERSION='6.5', KOTLIN_PLUGIN_VERSION='1.5.10')